# Что делает программа?

Tags: c

Вот есть такой код

```
#define MASK 0x15

int main() {

    char A[5] = {'a', 'B', 'c', 'D', 'e'};
    int I, RES = 0;
    for (I = 0; I < 5; I++)
        if ((A[I] & MASK) == MASK)
            RES++;
    printf("\n The result is : %d ", RES);
}
```

Нужно обьяснить, что он делает. Я насколько понял у нас есть масив из `char`, програма бежит по масиву и если биты этого чара содержаться в `MASK` то `RES` увеличиваем на 1.

Но у меня `printf()` показывает всегда 0. Я так понимаю, что либо есть ошибка в коде либо программа делает не то, что я думаю

Comment: 0 - правильно показывает, такая битовая маска нигде не встречается...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if ((A[I] & MASK) == MASK)` это контроль указанных битов. В вашем случае `MASK 0x15` указывает на три бита `10101`. Если в данных эти биты присутствуют, то результатом будет сама маска, а если один из этих битов равен нулю, то результат будет не равен маске.

Например 'a' == 97 == 0x61 == 1100001. Маска 10101 даст результат 00001. То есть один бит правильный, а два других нет.

Зачем у вас такая маска не знаю. Я бы считал количество маленьких букв с помощью маски 0x20.

Comment: Ну в целом, то что делает программа я описал в вопросе и вы это подтвердили, но меня насторожило, что дали такой вопрос а его вывод 0... Но мне понравилось ваше предпложение, может программа действительно должна считать маленькие буквы и ошибка в маске...

Answer (score -4):

В вашем коде, описание функции `printf`, содержится в заголовочном файле `stdio.h`, так как ввод-вывод не является встроенной возможностью C, то для использования `printf` вы обязаны подключить файл `stdio.h`.
Но это пол беды, в коде вы проверяете: `(A[I] && MASK) == MASK`, это означает, что сначала мы производим операцию И над элементом массива и маской, после чего сравниваем результат со значением маски, из этого следует что инкрементирование счётчика произойдёт только если значение элемента массива равно 21 (0x15), так что программа работает верно.